# How to Get Contact name, number and email ID from a list of Contacts?

Tags: android

I need to do get the details of all contacts when I press a Button, but my details include only 3 details

1. Contact Name
2. Contact number and
3. Email ID

I am using this code to get Contact name and number of all contacts, here is the code in my Button click

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;  
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GetNameNumberActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Button Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getContacts);
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (reqCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                Cursor cursor = null;
                String number = "";
                try {

                    Uri result = data.getData();

                    //get the id from the uri
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  

                    //query
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ? " , new String[] {id}, null);


                    int numberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);  

                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        number = cursor.getString(numberIdx);

                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //failed
                } finally {
                    if (cursor!=null) {
                        cursor.close();
                    }


                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code how can I add the section for getting email address.

Answer (score 4):

Your class is called `URLExample`, not `URLReader`.

You haven't said how you're launching it, but either you should change that to use `URLExample`, or you should change your class to be called `URLReader`. You should also format your code rather more readably...

Comment: Hello Jon Skeeet I have forgotten to change the name to URLReader.......

Comment: @P Abhilash: Well that would explain the error then...

Answer (score 0):

When I use

```
System.out.println(hpCon.getHeaderFields());
```

it prints

```
P3P=[CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."]
```

I suggest you read the link http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657

Comment: this link is helpful ..............thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is your URLExample class is not public and also check java file name and name of public class in file is same or not? it should be same.